# Android Parsing XML Problem with Character "<"

Tags: android, xml, parsing, character

I am parsing a XML file and wrap it into a DOM object. But I encountered a problem while parsing the tags(of the XML file) with the following format:

```
<Teaser><p>String Content Here</p></Teaser>
```

I viewed the source code of the tag, it's:

```
<Teaser>&lt;p&gt;String Content Here&lt;/p&gt;</Teaser>
```

Here's my code:

```
NodeList teaserList = list.getElementsByTagName("Teaser");
teaserLen=teaserList.getLength();
String [] newsTeaser = new String[teaserLen];
for(int n2=0;n2<teaserLen;n2++){
newsTeaser[n2]=teaserList.item(n2).getFirstChild().getNodeValue();

 }
```

But I am only getting "<" for each  tag.
Because there is a pair `<p></p>` inside `<Teaser></Teaser>`, I wonder if android takes `<p></p>` as another tag, so I try:

```
newsTeaser[n2]=teaserList.item(n2).getChildNodes().item(0).getFirstChild().getNodeValue();
```

But I am getting an error. So android is not taking `<p></p>` as another tag. 
Does anyone know what to do?? I would like to get all the text insider `<Teaser>`, thus getting: `<p>String Content Here</p>`

Comment: Can you show the code that gets the XML into the `list` variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shouldn't it be :

```
newsTeaser[n2]=teaserList.item(n2).getChildNodes().item(1).getNodeValue();
```